# Use python selenium webdriver in google colab without using --headless

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

I know like in this way we can import the webdriver in google colab

```
# install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install selenium
# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wd.get("https://www.website.com")
print(wd.page_source)  # results
# divs = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('div')
```

but due to this my website scraping is not working as the webdriver is headless

i wanted to use the whatsapp web for the scraping process

screenshot of the problem occur in acessing the website due to headless chrome
[image]

Comment: Try using chrome driver manager to use manage and use updated chrome driver

Comment: chrome drivers are updated it is headless so it is creating this kind of error i want to use withoutheadless in google colab